# Kotlin Fragment overlapping issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment, overlapping

I am using recyclerview. Then problem is when i click one of the row, new fragment should be open. It opens but, old fragment still appears. this is my screenshot:[image]

As you see, when i click "opel" new fragment opens. But it is overlapping.

This is my fragment 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvarackategori"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container">

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my new fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.aracYedekParca.chevrolet.ChevroletYedekParcaFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Chevrolet Yedek Parca" />

</FrameLayout>
```

this is my code:

```
override fun userItemClick(position: Int) {
        //super.userItemClick(position) No need of it.
        when (position) {
            0 -> {

                var fragmentOpel=OpelYedekParcaFragment()
                var transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.container,fragmentOpel)
                transaction.commit()

                Log.e("aki", "opel: " + position)
            } //start a fragment
            1 -> {

                var fragmentChevrolet=ChevroletYedekParcaFragment()
                var transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.container,fragmentChevrolet)
                transaction.commit()
                Log.e("aki", "chevrolet: " + position)
            } //start a fragment
```

Comment: Give a background to the old fragment ! and the new one !

Comment: But when i click back button, it should be go previous fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Add a background to your new Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background:"@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".ui.aracYedekParca.chevrolet.ChevroletYedekParcaFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Chevrolet Yedek Parca" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Changing backround is not a good idea. Because my recyclerview has click listener also.

Comment: @akiilhan I think it will not trigger the click listener on your previous fragment

Answer (score 1):

Basically that's how fragments work.

The methods name `replace` might be misleading, it doesn't replace the fragments it only lay a fragment in a layout.
so if you want the other fragment to be dismissed you have to remove it. otherwise just setting a background for your 2nd Fragment should workaround your issue

Comment: But when i click back button, it should be go previous fragment.

Comment: Then you have to keep the old Fragment and go with the solution with a background, and add the second fragment to the back stack by calling `transaction.addToBackStack(null);`